# Excel VBA defining a .Range with .Cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells

I'm running into a problem trying to select/copy certain ranges within my worksheet. I've narrowed it down as best as I can.

This works fine:

```
dataSheet.Cells(dRow, dataSheet.Range("IO_MODULES").Column).Select
```

This does not:

```
dataSheet.Range(Cells(dRow, dataSheet.Range("IO_MODULES").Column), Cells(dRow, dataSheet.Range("IO_MODULES").Column)).Select
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
dataSheet.Range(Cells(dRow, dataSheet.Range("IO_MODULES").Column), Cells(dRow, dataSheet.Range("MODULE_END").Column)).Copy Destination:= _
dataSheet.Range(Cells(dataSheet.Range("MODULE_1").Row + i - 1, dataSheet.Range("D_COUNT").Column + 1), Cells(dataSheet.Range("MODULE_1").Row + i - 1, dataSheet.Range("DATA_COL_END").Column))
```

I seem to be misunderstanding the relationship between Worksheet.Cells and Worksheet.Range. What I need to do is be able to select a range of cells based on the row and column numbers of cells that I've named.

Comment: On the whole, you're going to want to try and avoid using `.Select` -- here's a nice write-up about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: `Cells` is an unqualified range object, so it always is implicitly defined as `ActiveSheet.Cells`.  Therefore, you get an error with `dataSheet.Range(Cells(...` unless `dataSheet` **is** the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I overlooked that. Not sure what I was thinking using Cells like I was. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UNTESTED** try this to copy from one `Range` to another:

```
'...
Dim Source As Range, Dest As Range

With dataSheet
    Set Source = .Range(.Cells(dRow, .Range("IO_MODULES").Column), _
        .Cells(dRow, .Range("MODULE_END").Column))
    Set Dest = .Range(.Cells(.Range("MODULE_1").Row + i - 1, .Range("D_COUNT").Column + 1), _
        .Cells(.Range("MODULE_1").Row + i - 1, .Range("DATA_COL_END").Column))
    Source.Copy Dest
End With
```

1. The `With...End With` is in place to allow you to operate many times on a single object (in this case, `dataSheet`) without calling it explicitly every time. **Every line of code you write is a line that must be maintained and potentially debugged**, so when you can be more concise without losing readability you should do so. (More about `With...End With` statements here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264723(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264723%28v=office.15%29.aspx))
2. By naming the `Ranges` you can use the super-friendly `Range.Copy` method, outlined here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760%28v=office.15%29.aspx). This enables you to bypass a `.Select` or `.Activate`, which in my experience is a major source of run-time errors.

Comment: That did the job, thank you very much. Why do we need the range variables?

Comment: Dan your answer works of course but it would be a much better answer if you could explain *why* it works...

Comment: Naming the `Ranges` will allow you to use `Range.Copy`, which is outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837760(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: And... wrapped. +1 to @DavidZemens for pushing the explanation, not just the answer